# stringcomp: reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++

I just switched from C to C++, while everything was fairly easy in C(compared to C++). I migrated my program of sorting command line arguments in c to c++(i.e made classes and stuff) and now I am having this error when I try to run it. 
It is not able to find the reference for the function **stringcomp**. Can anyone help how to correct it ?
This question may be basic, so pardon my newness to c++.

PS: Par is my class Name

```
void Par :: sort()
{

    int i;
    char *s[size-1];


    /* assign each argument to a pointer */
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
        s[i-1] = argNew[i];

    qsort (s, size - 1, sizeof *s, stringcomp);//It yeilds an error here


    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
       argNew[i] = s[i-1];
    }

 }

void Par :: parse(char **argv, int argc)
{
setArgs(argv, argc);
sortArgs();
}

int Par:: stringcomp (const void *x, const void *y)
{
   return strcmp (*(char * const *)x, *(char * const *)y);
}
```

Comment: Why do you not just use `strcmp`?

Comment: Move stringcomp above  sort.

Comment: @ZDF I don’t think that will help; I think `Par` is a class, not a namespace.

Comment: @Daniel H because the function qsort won't accept it otherwise.

Comment: @DanielH I don't see stringcomp's declaration. - Sorry, I didn't notice Par in front of stringcomp.

Comment: @ZDF sorry for not being clear. It has been declared in the header file.

Comment: @ZDF You don’t see `Par`’s declaration either. This isn’t a minimal, complete, verifiable example. But look at the question title: `stringcomp` is a member function, so it is presumably one of `Par`.

Comment: is `size` a compile time constant expression?

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice stringcomp is a method. If it is not static, it won't work.

Comment: @user2079303 Based on context, I don’t think so. That means this isn’t standards-compliant C++ because VLAs aren’t supported, but it’s better to have something that works on some compilers than something which fails to work on all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member functions in C++ are special, they must be called from an instance of an object. The `qsort` function, being a holdover from C, doesn't know about objects and can't use it.

There are many ways to fix this. The first is to simply make `stringcomp` not a member function.

```
int stringcomp (const void *x, const void *y)
```

The second is to make it a *static* member function. Static functions don't need an object to be called against.

```
qsort (s, size - 1, sizeof *s, Par::stringcomp);
```

You should also consider using `std::sort`, it's the C++ way of doing sorting. You'll either need to implement `operator<` on your object, or provide a comparison function to the `sort` call. This comparison function is different from the one you use in C, and is a little beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `qsort` function from C isn’t the best way to do things in C++. It ignores types, which can cause a number of problems. These problems can happen in C as well, but they’re more visible in C++ because C++ tries to enforce types at compile time more.

In particular, the type error you originally had is that the type of `strcmp` is different from the type `qsort` wants, because the arguments are pointers to different types. The new error you have is that `stringcomp` is a *member function*, meaning it has a hidden third `this` parameter: it wants to know which `Par` object you’re calling it on. If you want to keep using `qsort` despite the type issues, then since you don’t need `this`, you should either make `stringcomp` static or better yet not put it in the `Par` class in the first place.

However, a better solution is to use the C++ `std::sort` function. You can call it as

```
std::sort(s, s + size, strcmp);
```

Even better would be to use `std::string`s instead of `char const*`s, because `std::string`s can do a lot of things faster by storing the size instead of relying on null-termination. Similarly, using a `std::vector` instead of an array will make memory management easier.